# Matplotlib some LaTeX symbols not scaling with increased figure sizes

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

> **SOLUTION**
>   A fix was to use `fixcmex` as outlined [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/447304/106804). Also, [this answer](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/11901#issuecomment-415255305) makes clear this is an issue with the underlying LaTeX.

I have noticed that when I increase the figure size to some very large sizes (for use on a very large and non-primary monitor) that not all the LaTeX symbols are being scaled correctly.

**e.g.**

When I use a very small figure size (which fits within the default monitor size) everything seems to be fine:

[image]

However, when I increase the figure sizes not all the symbols scale.

**the good**
[image]

**the bad**
[image]

**and the ugly**
[image]

Some of the problem symbols include `int`, `frac`, `sqrt` (display style), and scaling parentheses.

**Why mention default Ubuntu display?**

I know Matplotlib has some issues with canvases which are bigger than the default window size, e.g. [Initial plot window ignoring rcParams figure.figsize #10555](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10555#issuecomment-368670319), and [Add scrollbars when needed to preserve specified figure size #7338](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7338))

**The code:**

Using a virtual environment python 2.7.12 and matplotlib 2.2.3 and TkAgg backend on Ubuntu 16.04. (Not exactly MWE but close enough I hope).

```
import matplotlib as mpl
plt_style = 1 # Toggle this to see the difference
if plt_style == 0:  
    rc_fonts = {
        "text.usetex": True,
        "font.size": 30,
        'mathtext.default': 'regular',
        'axes.titlesize': 33,
        "axes.labelsize": 33,
        "legend.fontsize": 30,
        "xtick.labelsize": 30,
        "ytick.labelsize": 30,
        'figure.titlesize': 33,
        'figure.figsize': (15,9.3),
        'text.latex.preamble': [r'\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,bm,physics,lmodern}'],
        "font.family": "serif",
        "font.serif": "computer modern roman",
        }
elif plt_style == 1:
    rc_fonts = {
        "text.usetex": True,
        "font.size": 50,
        'mathtext.default': 'regular',
        'axes.titlesize': 55,
        "axes.labelsize": 55,
        "legend.fontsize": 50,
        "xtick.labelsize": 50,
        "ytick.labelsize": 50,
        'figure.titlesize': 55,
        'figure.figsize': (25, 16.5),  # 15, 9.3
        'text.latex.preamble': [r'\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,bm,fontenc,physics,lmodern,nicefrac}'],
        "font.family": "serif",
        "font.serif": "computer modern roman",
    }
elif plt_style == 2:
    rc_fonts = {
        "text.usetex": True,
        "font.size": 15,
        'mathtext.default': 'regular',
        'axes.titlesize': 16,
        "axes.labelsize": 16,
        "legend.fontsize": 15,
        "xtick.labelsize": 15,
        "ytick.labelsize": 15,
        'figure.titlesize': 16,
        'figure.figsize': (7.5,4.65),
        'text.latex.preamble': [r'\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,bm,physics,lmodern}'],
        "font.family": "serif",
        "font.serif": "computer modern roman",
        }
mpl.rcParams.update(rc_fonts)
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# e.g. An example plot

x = np.linspace(-3, 3, 1000)
y1 = np.exp(-0.5*x**2)/np.sqrt(2.0*np.pi)
y2 = np.sin(x)**2.0*np.exp(-0.5*x**2)/np.sqrt(2.0*np.pi)
plt.clf()  # I usually clear the current figure.
plt.plot(x, y1, 'k-', label='Standard Gaussian')
plt.plot(x, y2, 'r-', label='Modified Gaussian')
plt.legend(loc='upper left', frameon=False)
plt.title('Gaussian functions', y=1.02)  # A small vertical offset is usually nice.
plt.xlabel(r'$x$')
plt.ylabel(r'$f(x)$')
plt.ylim((0, 0.5))
plt.xlim((min(x), max(x)))
plt.gca().text(0.98, 0.98, r'$\displaystyle\int_\mathbb{R}^{} \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma}} \exp(-\dfrac{x^2}{2\sigma^2})} \dd{x} = 1 $', transform=plt.gca().transAxes, horizontalalignment='right', verticalalignment='top')
# plt.savefig('figures/gaussian_{}.pdf'.format(plt_style), format='pdf', bbox_inches='tight', transparent=True)
```

Comment: did not expect to see Ennio Morricone here